# Running Django on server with remote interpreter - Prevent Django from creating a test database

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm trying to use PyCharm's remote interpreter capability to debug my Django app on our dev server. The connection is working, but when I try to run or debug using the remote interpreter I get this error from the run console:

```
    Creating test database for alias 'default'...
    Failed (ORA-01031: insufficient privileges)
    Got an error creating the test database: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

As far as I can tell, Django is trying to create a test database to use with my test cases. I don't have any test cases on our server yet and don't need them right now. I'm also using my personal schema of which I am the owner. How can I prevent Django from trying to create this database so that I can run my code?

Comment: Why are you running tests if you don't have any test cases?

Comment: I'm not running any tests, I'm just trying to run the Django application on the server. The reason I'm doing it this way is that the code needs to be running on the server, but I also need to be able to use breakpoints. I can do this with pdb, but that's not ideal. If you think I'm going about this the wrong way or have any suggestions for other ways to accomplish this, I'd love to get your input.

Comment: But *what* are you doing? That message is from when you run `manage.py test`. Are you doing that? If not, what exactly are you running?

Comment: I'm doing this in PyCharm, so I'm just clicking the run button and it tries to execute the code on the server (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html). When I use the local interpreter, it doesn't try to create any databases or run tests, so I'm at a loss as to why it's trying to do that with the remote interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing, but the problem turned out to be that in my run configuration I had the 'test' box checked.